# Windows PowerShell & InfluxDB: Unable to Write Data to Bucket

Tags: python, influxdb

I am new to InfluxDB. Understand we need to use Windows Powershell to interact with InfluxDB.

Using Python in the shell, I tried to write data to the bucket using the below code

```
import influxdb_client, os, time
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point, WritePrecision
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS

token = os.environ.get("INFLUXDB_TOKEN")
org = "nil"
url = "https://us-west-2-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com/"

client = influxdb_client.InfluxDBClient(url=url, token=token, org=org)

bucket="MyBucket"

write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)
   
for value in range(5):
  point = (
    Point("measurement1")
    .tag("tagname1", "tagvalue1")
    .field("field1", value)
  )
  write_api.write(bucket=bucket, org="nil", record=point)
  time.sleep(1) # separate points by 1 second
```

**But I get the error**

```
influxdb_client.rest.ApiException: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Thu, 29 Dec 2022 01:44:17 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '55', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'trace-id': '5374d7ae5df282f4', 'trace-sampled': 'false', 'x-platform-error-code': 'unauthorized', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains', 'X-Influxdb-Request-ID': '2e52a39e6d7442b5fc7eb7306ef004d4', 'X-Influxdb-Build': 'Cloud'})
HTTP response body: {"code":"unauthorized","message":"unauthorized access"}
```

Answer (score 3):

401 indicates that there should something wrong with the authorization header. Could you try to enable to debug log as follows to see the details:

```
client = influxdb_client.InfluxDBClient(url=url, token=token, org=org, debug=True) // see that **debug=True** will enable verbose logging of HTTP requests
```

Both HTTP request headers and body will be logged to standard output. And please check the HTTP header to see whether there is "Authorization: Token" header, which is similar to

> Authorization: 7mexfXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Please double check if the header is missing or malformed.